# CSS expressions vs Filters and Javascript for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, css-expressions

What is the difference between CSS expressions and CSS Filters?

Are both bad for page speed?

If something can be achieved in pure CSS in other browsers but for IE only possible by CSS expressions or CSS Filters or Javascript. Then should we always go for Javascript, if we are concerning the page speed.

Will Javascript be quicker in rendering than CSS `Filter` or `Expression` solution?

---

**Update after Pekka's answer**

OK so CSS expressions should be avoided, it's clear.

Now I want to know about Filters

Example of filters

```
#myElement {
    opacity: .4; /* other browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40); /* this works in IE6, IE7, and IE8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=40)"; /* this works in IE8 only */
}
```

To get PNG Transparency in IE6 and some CSS 3 effect in IE 6,7,8 We can use CSS IE `Filters`

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

and there are also some Javascript alternative available.

Will Javascript be quicker in rendering than CSS Filter ?

**Note:** The `filter` property is not valid CSS

Answer (score 1):

In older versions of IE, if you have the choice to use a CSS filter or a CSS expression, the filter is the better choice.

However, I can't think of a single scenario where you have the *choice* of a filter *or* an expression.

You should favor plain Javascript over expressions, because expressions are evaluated *constantly*, for instance on `mousemove`. With plain Javascript, you can control when the code runs, for example `onload`, or `onresize`.

See a Google [document on the subject](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/rendering.html#AvoidCSSExpressions):

> CSS expressions degrade rendering
>   performance; replacing them with
>   alternatives will improve browser
>   rendering for IE users.
>
> Note: This best practices in this
>   section apply only to Internet
>   Explorer 5 through 7, which support
>   CSS expressions. CSS expressions are
>   deprecated in Internet Explorer 8, and
>   not supported by other browsers.

---

The things filters are used for in IE, there is often no way to replace them.

There is no way to "use Javascript" instead, because the Javascript will just be dynamically applying the filter. This is the case for transparency, and the rgba gradient filter workaround.

---

**In response to your edit:**

> and there are also some Javascript
>   alternative available.
>
> Will Javascript be quicker in
>   rendering than CSS Filter ?

In the [article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/) you linked to, none of workarounds have a `filter` solution *and* a Javascript solution (the ones that do are just applying the same `filter` automatically, for convenience).

Comment: I also found this for filters http://gtmetrix.com/avoid-alphaimageloader-filter.html

Comment: PNG8 is a nice solution if it works in your instance of the problem (what if you need the full colour depth of PNG24?), but it requires extra work to export PNG8 versions of your image(s) which will probably only be used for older IE. [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/#technical_summary) is another solution for transparency which uses VML to handle the problem.

Comment: you wrote "In the article you linked to, none of workarounds have a filter solution" but it has many solution with filter. I didn't get you

Comment: @JitendraVyas: I said "none of the workarounds have a filter solution **AND** a JavaScript solution". Meaning that you have no choice but to use the filter solution (and if a JavaScript solution *did* exist, it would just be applying the same filter solution anyway so there would be no speed increase).

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to IE6's CSS Expressions, you should totally drop those and use jQuery.

IE CSS expressions

- Used to work only in IE up to 7
- Have been [discontinued by Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx)
- Achieve nothing that jQuery can't do, it's just a bit more convenient
- According to [this](http://robertnyman.com/2007/11/13/stop-using-poor-performance-css-expressions-use-javascript-instead/), they used to require JavaScript to be enabled
- In conclusion, were a bad idea.

Comment: OK and what about Filters http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/28/css3-solutions-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: @Jitendra well, they are the only solution for some effects in IE7 so you may need them. But they obviously suck because they are supported in IE